# how to edit items saved in a list app inventor

Tags: android

so i have just started using app inventor and have made an app to persistently store data in a list. i have also made is possible to delete data from the list by using before and after picking blocks.

what i am struggling with is figuring out how to be able to edit items in a list so for example they load the note saved as cheese it bring up all the data for it, what i would like to be able to do is when they load the note by clicking the edit listpicker  when the note is saved again the value previously stored in the listpicker is replaced with the new one.

can i use the same before and after picking as i did for delete or is it different.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know its late to answer but try here:

http://www.newthinktank.com/2014/05/connect-app-inventor-mysql-database/

This tutorial will go thru the whole process of adding items to mysql db using php and app inventor, and in particular should answer the section on updating items selected using listpicker.

Comment: While this link might answer the question, it is considered to be a good practice to summarize the relevant parts on stackoverflow too, just in case it gets removed. [answer]